# How do you use ad hoc polymorphism/function overloading with functions in Python?

Tags: python, functions, polymorphism

So, let's say you've got a function foobar() which can function with a variable number of parameters inputted into it, and has different behavior for each of them. How do you get this to function properly in Python? Are you forced to name every possible combination of parameters something different?

For instance, let's take the following code:

```
def foobar(foo):
    print(foo)

def foobar(foo,bar):
    print(foo+bar)

foobar("Hello")
foobar("Hello","World")
```

This gives the following error: "TypeError: foobar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'". If you reverse the order of foobar(foo) and foobar(foo,bar), you instead get the error "TypeError: foobar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". From this, it seems like Python only stores one copy of foobar(), related to whichever version was the latest to be defined.

How do you get code like this to function properly in Python? Is there a "Pythonic" way of accomplishing this goal? I can see a bunch of other questions asking about polymorphism in Python, but none of them seem to address this issue; they all seem to be talking about different classes with methods that use the same name, or passing different sorts of variables into a function as a parameters.

Comment: FYI, function overloading is ad hoc polymorphism, not parametric.

Comment: Really? I just remembered that it was polymorphism and involved parameters, so when I did a Google search and that was the term that came up, it was the term I went with. Editted the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways. The easiest is probably to use a default parameter:

```py
def foobar(foo, bar=None):
    if bar is None:
        print(foo)
    else:
        print(foo+bar)
```

The other is to use `*args` or `**kwargs`, in which case all your extra arguments can be treated as a collection.